# OWL API - create class without instances

Tags: java, ontology, owl, owl-api

I have a requirement to create a class in the Ontology using the OWL-API without adding any instances.

I checked the examples and the documentation but all the places the classes are created along with the individuals/ instances. Is there a way to create classes without any instances (and and them later on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I wanted to create a modelling element such as a class without instances from an input string I would do something like:

```
OWLEntity entity = factory.getOWLEntity(EntityType.CLASS, IRI.create(input));
```

The `EntityType.CLASS` could be changed to other elements such as `EntityType.ObjectProperty`. This is the way I approach this problem and when I want to add instances I just add a new axiom to the ontology manager.

Comment: Thanks!!! that basically solves my problem. I then added the created entity as and OWLDeclarationAxiom to the OWLOntologyManager object

Comment: Does this have any advantage for @jana's use case over the more specific (and more readable, in my opinion), `factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(input))` that's [shown in the examples](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/master/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/Examples.java#L275)?

Comment: I don't know generally, but for Manchester Syntax you need to specify the type. Thus having the type there.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor's comment is correct: both methods will create the same result.

Answer (score 3):

It is never necessary to add instances to declare and use a class.

For example:

```
OWLClass c = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(cInput));
OWLAxiom declareC = factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(c);
// adding declareC to the ontology is necessary to have any output
manager.addAxiom(ontology, declareC);
```

In order to get any entity outputted when saving an ontology, it must be used in some axiom included in the ontology. In this example, that axiom is the class declaration; it could be a subclass axiom or an assertion (in that case, an instance will be created).